# Ruby while and cond related clarification

Tags: ruby

In the following code:

```
def my_while(cond, &body)
  while cond.call
    body.call
  end
end

a = 0
my_while -> { a < 3 } do
  puts a
  a += 1
end
```

What is the purpose of

```
def my_while(cond, &body)
  while cond.call
    body.call
```

and how is that affecting the loop?

Comment: there is no `while.call`.

Comment: I mean while cond.call

Answer (score 0):

The arguments to `my_while` are being processed as blocks.

The `cond` argument, which is the comparison `{ a < 3 }`, is being executed by the call as the test condition in the `while` within the function.  Each time that is true, the second argument, `&body`, is being executed.

It's a really complicated way of writing a while loop but is apparently being used to demonstrate passing around code blocks which can be quite useful in metaprogramming applications.

Comment: If you say complicated then I shall drop the thought of understanding it. I started learning Ruby last week and everything is confusing me!
Thanks and I really appreciate your effort.

Comment: Well, wherever you found that, go somewhere else. :)  The beauty of Ruby is the flexibility of notation and the natural clarity.  That doesn't mean that it can't be abused to do crazy things.  :)  That said, this type of operation can be very powerful, but I can't think of any reason someone would replace the built in `while` with that abstraction.

Comment: I learn ruby on my way to work. Its a PDF book I downloaded. I will skip that section then. Thanks David!